# Should I use docker-compose start or docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker-compose

It is not quite clear to me if there is any difference executing:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose start
```

or

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [PR open for adding this to the FAQ](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2291/files#diff-956da29f025cba37fca9fe6b80ab5d48R55).

You want `up -d`.  `build` + `start` isn't going to do anything, because no containers were created. `build` builds images, it doesn't create containers.

`up -d` takes care of building when the images doesn't already exist, creating containers if they don't exist (or have changed), and starting the containers.

You may want `build` and `up -d` if your image changes.